# "Would" vs. "would have", "could" vs. "could have", "should" vs. "should have"

Tags: verbs, present-tense, mood

What is a good example to understand these words at once? I am quite confused by these and feel like I am using them incorrectly. Please guide me how and when to use them properly.

E.g., "I eat rice".

- If I use *will*, "I will eat rice", it means I am going to eat at some point in the future.
- If I use *would*, "I would eat rice", does that mean the same thing? When can I use it?
- If I use *would have*, "I would have eaten rice", it's about the past.

Likewise for "I could eat rice" vs. I could have eaten rice"; "I should eat rice" vs. "I should have eaten rice"; "I may eat rice" vs. "I may have eaten rice"; "I might eat rice" vs. "I might have eaten rice"; "I had eaten rice" vs. "I have eaten rice" vs. "I have had eaten rice".

I went through my English books but kind of messed up which to use when.

Comment: What does your grammar say?

Comment: Please do proofread your writing. The "I" is capitalized, "its" is not the same thing as "it's", "quiet" is not the same as "quite", "i.e." is not the same as "e.g.". Sentences begin with capital letters, and questions end in question marks. And there is no such thing as a double full stop (not just in English, in any language). Not paying attention to this basic stuff puts your writing into a register where it simply does not matter if you use "should", "should have", or "should of". Please put the same effort into your question as you expect people to put into their answers. Thank you.

Comment: That being said, this question is way too broad in its current form, so I have to put it on hold as such. It is indeed several completely unrelated questions in one. The questions are also too basic for this site, check out [our sister site for learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/). Again, before re-posting there, make sure to narrow down your question and include your research so far. What *did* your English books say?

Comment: Please can you state me where i can find the correct ruling for proper writing ?

Answer (score 1):

You have two levels of uncertainty here (technically, "moods"):

Certain

> - I will eat rice
> - I have eaten rice
> - I had eaten rice

Uncertain

> - I would eat rice
> - I would have eaten rice
> - I should eat rice
> - I should have eaten rice
> - I may eat rice
> - I may have eaten rice
> - I might eat rice
> - I might have eaten rice

Essentially with these, you need to make decisions:

1. Does the action take place in the present or past?

   - If it is in the past > have
2. Is it certain or uncertain? If it is uncertain, it is because of:

   - Your need or obligation > "should"
   - Your intention > "will"
   - Your ability > "may"
   - Your potential > "might"
   - Condition > "would"
     This last one is more difficult, it's generally used in the form `I would do [this], but [something else prevented it]` or `I would do [this], if [something else is the case]`

There is also the combination:

> I will have eaten rice

Which means that, at some point in the future, you will eat rice, and have completed eating (some) rice.

You also have an ungrammatical example:

> - I have had eaten rice

Comment: And, Could means possibility if i am not incorrect.